# How to create a link from button values for woocommerce order

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to generate a add to cart link for a page from value inputed by our customer. For example, the customer wants to order 3 products from our site www.example.com, so the code generates a link to add these 3 product to cart on page www.example2.com/?add-to-cart=25&quantity=3″.

Any ideas? I would be very grateful.

Here is the qet quantity code which works like a charm.

```
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickUP();">+</button>
<input type="text" id="gumb2" value="1"></input>
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickDOWN();">-</button>
<input type="text" id="order" value="ORDER NOW"></input>
<script>
  function spremembax() {
     document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "2";
  }

  function spremembay() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "3";
  }
  var i = 0;

  function buttonClickUP() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    el.value = Number(el.value) + 1;
  }
  var i = 0;

  function buttonClickDOWN() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    if(el.value == 1) return false;
    el.value = Number(el.value) - 1;
      }

</script>
```

Comment: What is the `25` in the URL? Where does it come from?

Comment: It is supposed to be the product ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code sample which I wrote for you which does the job:

JSBIN Snippet Link: https://jsbin.com/guborazuqu

```js
function spremembax() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "2";
}

function spremembay() {
    document.getElementById("gumb2").value = "3";
}
var i = 0;

function buttonClickUP() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    el.value = Number(el.value) + 1;
}
var i = 0;

function buttonClickDOWN() {
    var el = document.getElementById('gumb2');
    if (el.value == 1) return false;
    el.value = Number(el.value) - 1;
}


function generateAddToCartLink() {
    var productID = document.getElementById('productID').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('gumb2').value;
    var generatedLink = `${location.protocol}//${location.hostname}/?add-to-cart=${productID}&quantity=${quantity}`;
    window.location.href = generatedLink;
}
```

```html
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickUP();">+</button>
<input id="productID" type="text" value="25"> 
<input id="gumb2" type="text" value="1"> 
<button class="plus" onclick="buttonClickDOWN();">-</button> 
<button id="order" onclick="generateAddToCartLink()">ORDER NOW</button>
```

Comment: This is correct but i want this to be appended directly to url bar so when customer clicks order it auto reddirects him to this page.